# Should Let-Me-Ins be affecting my legs this much?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, you-are-your-own-gym

I'm trying to get through Mark Lauren's *You Are Your Own Gym* Beginner program, as per my earlier question on ladders, [Failure in ladder exercises - Am I misunderstanding rest periods?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/failure-in-ladder-exercises-am-i-misunderstanding-rest-periods). When doing the "Let-Me-Ins", I'm finding that my legs seem to be taking the brunt of the effort. My arms, chest, and back are fine, but my legs are burning within a few reps. I know that I'm still hurting a bit from leg day, but is this normal?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPvK5FamZKY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, [yes, it's perfectly normal](http://yayog-fitocracy.wikia.com/wiki/Let_Me_Ins). While the exercise is supposed to work only the back and legs, a lot of people have trouble with the static position. Some tips from the Fitocracy wiki:

> - Use some rope
> - I noticed that I had the tendency to rock back on my heels, even every so slightly just shifting the weight. I felt less of that when I tried to keep my toes down and feet flat on the ground.
> - Trying extra hard not to lean my weight back helped a little.

Mainly, they seem to counsel just doing the exercise day after day and it will get better.